# What loop to use in javascript that runs a certain code before it ends

Tags: javascript

My questions says exactly what i want.

A loop that runs till it's got to. Then when ending, condition doesn't meet, do something else.

I thought of this...

`for(var t=0; (t>10)||(//code here); t++)` but obviously this is broken and ugly.

Comment: If you want something to just run after your loop is over, why not just put it after the loop ends?

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand what you want.

Comment: So `t` starts at zero, runs when `t > 10` or the other condition are true, and increments by one.  If the 2nd condition is not true at the start, the loop will never run because `t` must be greater than 10.  If `t` does get to 10, you're going to have a hung script because t will always be greater than 10 from that iteration onward.

Comment: nvm i don't know what i was thinking then...

Comment: i meant that run it if loop ends and if it's broken out than don't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you thinking of something like a do while loop?

```
var x="",i=0;
 do
 {
   x=x + "The number is " + i + "<br>";
   i++;
 }
 while (i<5);
```

The do/while loop is a variant of the while loop. This loop will execute the code block once, before checking if the condition is true, then it will repeat the loop as long as the condition is true.  From `w3schools.com`

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't super clear but, there are the two `while` loops:

The `while` loop, checks for a condition every iteration:

```
while (someCondition) {
    // ...
}
```

The `do while` loop, runs once and then checks for a condition every subsequent iteration:

```
do {
    // ...
} while (someCondition)
```

---

The `break` keyword may also be useful to you, this exits the loop when it's called.

```
for (var t=0; t<10; t++) {
    if (someCondition) {
        break; // exit the loop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to run a loop UP TO 10 times, but if the other condition has not yet been met, then keep going?

One idea is to use a while loop (for the other condition) with a counter to break out in case of endless loop.

```
var cnt = 0;
while (result != "Bob") {
    //do some stuff
      cnt++;

    if (cnt > 10) break
}
if (result != "Bob") {
    //Do something else
}
```